# PowerShell reports missing method, when method exists

Tags: powershell-2.0

I've had a problem recently with PowerShell reporting that a method does not exist on an object, while `Get-Member` reports that it does. This doesn't happen with all methods, but I have had it happen in more than one instance.

Here's a screenshot of one example in the ISE.

[image]

Comment: It seems like .Remove expects two `int` parameters and you're feeding it a string. Try $x.Remove(0,1) instead?

Comment: @NathanC Shouldn't it be giving me a different error then, instead of "doesn't contain a method"? ETA: `$x.Remove(0,1)` fails with same error.

Answer (score 1):

Your `$x` variable holds an array. When you pipe an array into a function, the pipeline doesn't pass the array *instance* into the function; it passes the array's *elements* into the function's `process` block, one at a time.

`Get-Member` is actually showing you the members of the string `'c'` -- the last element in the array -- rather than the members of the array itself. (Notice that the output in your screenshot starts with `TypeName: System.String`.)

If you want to see the members for `$x` (the array) itself, pass it into `Get-Member` using the `-InputObject` parameter, instead of piping it in.

```
$X='a','b','c'; gm -InputObject $x
```

Then you'll see that your `$x` is of type `System.Object[]` and doesn't contain a `Remove` method. (You can't remove items because that would change the array's length, and arrays in .NET are fixed-length.)